# VIM: How to grep within a specific file list or directory list (ie not recursively) and have results in quickfix window?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I work with multiple fairly large projects with 1600+ files across 125+ directories each, but those files are interspersed with larger projects with many times that number of files and directories, which make recursive searching from the top of the project too slow and unwieldy.  And I'd rather not preemptively load all those files into vim's buffers.

Fortunately, these projects have fairly good filelists that I've can parse to setup project-specific vimrc files (project.vimrc) that right now just contain a lot of "set path+=/path/to/dir" which works great for enabling stuff like "gf" to work quickly.

I'd like to find a grep solution to search for a string in the given filelist or in the directories in vim's path variable, and have it list results in the quickfix window.  Is there a way to do this?

Most of the existing grep solutions seem to want you to specify the top directory and recurse, or let you grep through the files already loaded into the buffers.

Comment: Have you considered [Ack](http://beyondgrep.com/) , [Ag the Silver Surfer](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher), or git grep? These are all typically much faster than grep. All these including normal grep and `:vimgrep` can take an additional directory parameter.

Comment: I've looked at those, but they seem to want you to specify a top directory to recurse down from, or load all your files into the vim buffers.  Its very possible I missed something, however.

Comment: I have a repo with 4700+ files and both git grep and ag return results in less than a second. Ack supports `--files-from=FILE` and `-x` which takes files to be searched over from a file or stdin. I would suggest you not dismiss this out of hand. However you may also want to look into ctags, cscope, or global.

Comment: That was it.  I missed the --file-from=FILE option since I only looked at the doc for ack.vim.  That is exactly what I was looking for and it works like a charm!!

Do you want to move your comment to an answer so I can accept it officially?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep` can take multiple directories to search recursively like via `grep -r foo/ bar/` (See `man grep` and `:h :grep` for more information). However grep can be a bit slow with many files. There are some nice alternatives:

- [Ack](http://beyondgrep.com/) is faster than regular grep because it skips VCS directories, binary files, and can search for specific type of filetypes like `--perl`. For Vim integration see [Ack.vim](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim)
- [Ag the Silver Surfer](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) is a code-searching tool similar to ack, but faster. Vim plugin: [Ag.vim](https://github.com/rking/ag.vim)
- `git grep` searches a repository very quickly. [Fugitive.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) provides `:Ggrep`.

I recommend both Ag and `git grep` as they are both super fast. I have searched over 4700+ in less than a 1 second.

To test out one of these alternatives without a plugin or you simply don't want a plugin you can set your `'grepprg'` option accordingly. e.g. `set grepprg=ack`. See `:h 'grepprg'` for more information.

If you really need to search a specific list of files Ack has `--files-from=FILE` and `-x` options which take a list of files in the form of file or stdin respectively.

Other tools which may be of some help for some programming languages are:

- [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) builds a symbol database and allows you to jump to symbols. See `:h tags-and-searches`
- [Cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/) is a tool like ctags, but think of it as ctags on steroids since it
  does a lot more than what ctags provides.
- `locate` unix tool much like find except it uses a prebuilt database. See `man locate` and Tim Pope's [vim-eunuch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-eunuch).
- [GNU global](http://www.gnu.org/software/global/manual/global.html) is another symbol database that provides ctag/cscope like options as well.

As a final fallback you can use `:vimgrep` as it is available on all systems that Vim is available. See `:h :vimg` for more help.

As most of these options use the quickfix list I suggest you use some more friendly mappings to transverse the quickfix list. I use Tim Pope's [unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) plugin which uses `]q` and `[q` for `:cnext` and `:cprev` respectively. Some people like the quickfix to open after a search is performed then add the following to your `~/.vimrc` file: `autocmd QuickFixCmdPost *grep* cwindow`

In conclusion you have many options however I personally doubt you can beat `git grep` or Ag in for general searching needs. I also use GNU Global for my symbol needs.

Comment: `grep -I` to skip binary files; `grep --include=<wildcard>` for filename/extension filtering; `grep --exclude-dir={.git,.svn}` to skip VCS (as an example);

Answer (score 1):

If your `'path'` option already contains a list of interesting directories, you can pass that on to `:vimgrep`, like this:

```
:execute 'vimgrep /pattern/' join(map(split(&path, ','), 'v:val . "/*"'))
```

This appends `/*` to each path, so that any files inside that directory are searched.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.